# In the context of ServiceMix/CXF, what does 'transport' mean?

Tags: java, cxf, esb, apache-servicemix

I have identified a concept pervading many components and ServiceMix elements. The term is **transport**.

I have seen it used when defining CXF endpoints mostly. See for example this thread post: [how to build camel-cxf consumer with osgi](http://fusesource.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10613#10627)

You can read 'OSGi transport' and 'Jetty transport' in the same reply. I also have used (without much awareness of what I'm doing, I must admit, as I am still learning about ServiceMix) *classpath:META-INF/cxf/transport/nmr/cxf-transport-nmr.xml* which makes me think there is also a 'NMR transport'.

Can anyone explain what a 'transport' is in this context?

Thanks